# Displaying rows in a table first with checked checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, html-table

I have table displayed with checkboxes in each row like this-

[image: Table]

**Html code :** -

```
<table>
     <tr>
        <td><input type= "checkbox"></td>
        <td>Name1</td>
        <td>Role1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><input type= "checkbox"></td>
        <td>Name2</td>
        <td>Role2</td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
        <td><input type= "checkbox"></td>
        <td>Name4</td>
        <td>Role4</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><input type= "checkbox"></td>
        <td>Name3</td>
        <td>Role3</td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

I also have a button 'Sort'. When I click on the button sort, all those rows which have checkboxes as checked should be displayed first and all other rows after them. The result would look something like this -

[image: Result table]

How can this be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jquery you can parse each `<tr>` and check if their child checkbox is check then add them to a new table as first or last child. then replace the old table with the new one.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sort').on('click', function(){
        var newTable = $('<table class="table"></table>');
         $('.table').find('tr').each(function($index, $value){
            if($(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked')){
                newTable.prepend($(this));
            } else {
                newTable.append($(this));
            } 
         });
         $('.table').replaceWith(newTable);
    });
});
```

this should work but i havn't tested it yet.
Hopes it helps !

- Nic

Comment: Hey! Thanks for this. I tried doing this but it doesn`t work. I am not sure if the .replaceWith is capable of doing it. Please see here - https://jsfiddle.net/vjwr6fxq/

Comment: @Stringified Hi yea you needed jquery and there was a little error but i fixed it, here it goes ! https://jsfiddle.net/vjwr6fxq/10/

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
$('input').each(function(e,i){
 if(!i.checked){
   var tr=$(i).closest('tr');
     $(tr).parent().append($(tr).remove());
    }
 });
```

Comment: Hey! I tried doing this, it doesn`t seem to work. Please look here - https://jsfiddle.net/w3d2x271/

Comment: sorry i dont think it works on jsfiddle , plz see [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BLOqpo)

Comment: Oh that`s strange, yes I checked, its working on codepen. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort()` and `is(':checked')` to sort rows and then empty table and append sorted content. [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1269/)

```
var sorted = $('table tr').sort(function(a, b) {
  if($(b).find('td:first-child input').is(':checked')) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
})

$('button').click(function() {
  $('table').empty().html(sorted);
})
```

Comment: since the table gets emptied losing the refernce of tr in it, trying to click on the button is not sorting more than once i guess

Comment: @Nenand Hey! Tried doing this but actually the attribute 'checked' is not by default true when the page loads, as is in your demo. It works for that but on button click it doesn`t. I think @nivendha is right. But thanks for this.